# UK naturalization background checks what is the meaning?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, uk-residents

What is the meaning of this question on UK naturalization background check

> Your application will be refused if you have attempted to deceive the
> Home Office within the last 10 years.

Does this only concern immigration related issues?

What do they mean by `within the last 10 years`?

Comment: This question is not about travel (which for this site means short term travel like vacations), and will probably be moved to our [expatriates.se] site, which covers living and working abroad.

Comment: So basically the home office checks are 10 years

Answer (score 4):

In general, it means an application will normally be refused only where the person has attempted to lie or conceal the truth about an aspect of their application, whether on the application form or in the course of enquiries, including where they have knowingly provided false personal details, for example date of birth, name or nationality.

The types of deception or dishonesty considered when assessing good character in citizenship applications are:

**Deceitful or dishonest dealings with Her Majesty’s Government**

An application will normally be refused where the person has attempted to deceive or otherwise been clearly dishonest in their dealings with another government department.

Examples might include but are not limited to:

• fraudulently claiming or otherwise defrauding the benefits system

• unlawfully accessing services (for example, housing or health care) for which access is controlled by immigration legislation

• providing dishonest information in order to acquire goods or services (for example, providing false details in order to obtain a driving licence)

• providing false or deliberately misleading information at earlier stages of the immigration application process (for example, providing false bio-data, claiming to be a nationality they were not or concealing conviction data).

**Failure to disclose information required in a nationality application**

Where the applicant fails to disclose information that would result in the application being refused on good character grounds, the application must be refused and any further application for citizenship will normally be refused for the next 10 years. This applies unless it is accepted that the failure to disclose was unintentional and a genuine error.

**Deception in previous applications**

An application will normally be refused where there is evidence that a person has employed deception either:

• during the citizenship application process
• in a previous immigration application in the previous 10 years.

**Within the last 10 years** means *in the 10 years prior to the application for citizenship*. For these purposes, the deception is regarded as continuing until the date on which it is discovered or admitted. For example, if a person used deception in an application in 2002, but that was discovered or admitted to in 2011, the 10-year period would start in 2011.

Source: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/923656/good-character-guidance-v2.0-gov-uk.pdf#page41

Comment: what If the immigration-related issue happens 19 years ago?????

Comment: IANAL but my interpretation of the guidance is that if an immigration issue happened 19 years ago and was not disclosed in any subsequent application to the UK, the 10 year ineligibility period starts on the day the issue is disclosed/discovered *not* on the date the issue occurred.

Answer (score 2):

> Your application will be refused if you have attempted to deceive the Home Office within the last 10 years. Immigration Related Issues??????????

Not only for Immigration Related Issues, but for any area they are responsible for within the last 10 years. If you have a clear record over the last 10 years, older events may be ignored. Criminal records would not be ignored.

> [About us - Home Office - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/home-office/about)
> **Responsibilities**
> We are responsible for:
>
> - working on the problems caused by illegal drug use
> - shaping the alcohol strategy, policy and licensing conditions
> - keeping the United Kingdom safe from the threat of terrorism
> - reducing and preventing crime, and ensuring people feel safe in their homes and communities
> - securing the UK border and controlling immigration
> - considering applications to enter and stay in the UK
> - issuing passports and visas
>   supporting visible, responsible and accountable policing by empowering the public and freeing up the police to fight crime
> - fire prevention and rescue

Comment: Thank you for your feedback it's the same 10 year  within 10 year period for British overseas territory applicant background checks

Comment: @Lion The 10 year period is not absolute. An application will normally be refused if there has been any deception in previous immigration applications in the 10 years prior to the application for citizenship. For these purposes, the deception is regarded as continuing until the date on which it is discovered or admitted. For example, if a person used deception in an application in 2008, but that was discovered or admitted to in 2010, the 10-year period would start in 2010.

Comment: The immigration issue happen in 2002 .